# Creating dynamic range using xlup

Tags: excel, vba

im trying to create a master file using vba to control various excel (dependants) files. Once the master file is open and running the macro, it will go through the directory, open the various excel files and copy paste the relevant columns to the master file. (i.e 3 dependant excel files (AA,BB,CC). i need to pull out column A to D in AA, C in BB and Z in CC.)

My current code is able to do so but i have to have a static range established for the copy paste. Which is the following line: Range("A2:B6").copy. I am trying to render the range dynamic as such: Range ("A2: D & last row with info). copy

```
Sub LoopThroughDirectory()
Dim MyFile As String
Dim erow
Dim Filepath As String

Filepath = "E:\Excel\"
MyFile = Dir(Filepath)
Do While Len(MyFile) > 0


If MyFile = "Name&Age.xlsx" Then
Workbooks.Open ("E:\Excel\Name&Age")
Range("A2:B6").Copy
ActiveWorkbook.Close

erow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(erow, 1), Cells(erow, 2))
End If

If MyFile = "Food&Quantity.xlsx" Then
Workbooks.Open ("E:\Excel\Food&Quantity")
Range("D2:E6").Copy
ActiveWorkbook.Close

erow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(erow, 3), Cells(erow, 4))
End If

MyFile = Dir
Loop
End Sub
```

I've tried to modified and use the following:

```
If MyFile = "Name&Age.xlsx" Then
Workbooks.Open ("E:\Excel\Name&Age")
erow1 = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Range(Cells(A, 2), Cells(B, erow1)).Copy
ActiveWorkbook.Close
```

But i keep getting error 1004. I think the problem lies in the following code: Range(Cells(A, 2), Cells(B, erow1)).Copy

Any ideas?

Hey simoco, thanks for your help, i tried code but it seems to take the row under last row with data (row which is empty). (for example, D2 to D6 has data, and E2 to E6 also). When using the following code, if i step into the code, i see that vba selects range:D7 to E all rows.

here's the code:

```
If MyFile = "Food&Quantity.xlsx" 
Then Workbooks.Open ("E:\Excel\Food&Quantity")
erow3 = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Sheet1.Range("D2:E" & erow3).Copy
ActiveWorkbook.Close

erow4 = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(erow4, 3), Cells(erow4, 4))
End If
```

FOR Toni,

Thanks for the input. The code works perfectly for static range. i do not receive any 1004 error. Even when copying and closing workbook before pasting it in another workbook. I did think of a "dumb" solution for it. I could use Range("A2:B1000000000000").copy but im wondering if there is a more "pretty" solution.
Also, i did just try it with B100000000. it ran without error.

Comment: try `Sheet1.Range("A2:B" & erow1).Copy`

Comment: Hey simoco, its a weird problem, since using alone: erow3 = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row and msgbox erow3. give me a msgbox with "6". i dont know why the selected range is D7.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of problems with your code.

**Issue 1**

With the keyboard interface you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to copy a range to the scratchpad.  You can then move the cursor to the required destination, in a different workbook if necessary, and use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> to paste the range.  But, if you do anything other than move the cursor, you lose the copy.  The same is true with VBA.  I have never attempted a workbook close between a copy and a paste and I very much doubt it would work.  I believe this is the cause of error 1004.

I do not like using `ActiveWorkbook` when I have multiple workbooks open because I loose track of which workbook is active.  I suspect your problem is you do not know how to access anything other than the `ActiveBookbook`.  This following macro shows how to create workbook objects that allow you to address specific workbooks.

```
Option Explicit
Sub Test()

  Dim WbookDest As Workbook
  Dim WbookSrc As Workbook

  ' This creates a workbook object for the workbook containing the macro.
  Set WbookDest = ThisWorkbook

  ' This opens workbook xxxx and creates a workbook object for it.
  Set WbookSrc = Workbooks.Open("xxxx")

  ' This displays the names of the open workbooks
  Debug.Print "Dest: " & WbookDest.Name
  Debug.Print " Src: " & WbookSrc.Name

  ' This closes the source workbook
  WbookSrc.Close

End Sub
```

**Issue 2**

You use `Dir` and a loop to get the names of the files in the folders but you open specific workbooks.  I do not understand why you are using `Dir`.

**Issue 3**

Instead of `Copy` and `Paste`, which match keyboard commands, there is a VBA statement that I find more convenient:

```
Dim CellDest As Range
Dim RngSrc As Range

Set RngSrc = Desired range within worksheet of source workbook
Set CellDest = Top left cell of desired range within worksheet of destination workbook

WbookSrc.RngSrc.Copy Destination := WbookDest.CellDest
```

**Suggestion**

I suggest you try addressing the above issues and come back with questions as necessary.

Comment: Hi tony, you were right. I just solved my problem by activating workbooks and making sure which was activated before copying. My only question is for a range data set, you can copy it by opening the excel file and worksheet without activating it without any problem. While with a dynamic one, you need to open excel, activate workbook & worksheet. Why is that?

Comment: Opening a workbook automatically makes it the active workbook.  I do not believe there is anything you can do to avoid that.  Why do you think you need to activate the worksheet with a dynamic range?  `Paste` operates on active workbook but `Copy` does not.

Comment: i dont know why i need to activate the worksheet with a dynamic range. Since in my initial code (static range); when i step into the code and checked the values. my range was Range("A2:B6").Copy. which was correct. With the dynamic code,                         erow1 =Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Range(Cells(A, 2), Cells(B, erow1)).Copy. The range was A2:A1 and targeted my worksheet which i was pasting to. I figured that if i activate the worksheet which needed the copy then put in the code, it would force it to copy from the right worksheet

Comment: I assume `Range(Cells(A, 2), Cells(B, erow1)).Copy` is a typo since it is `Cells(Row, Column)`. `Range` and `Cells` apply to the active worksheet unless qualified.  I would guess you forgot to qualify something.